# What is the equivalent of 'nohup' in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, nohup

How can I emulate the behavior of the unix command `nohup` in PowerShell? That is `nohup my-other-nonblocking-command`. I have noticed the `Start-Job` command, however the syntax is somewhat unclear to me.

Comment: Powershell is backwards compatible, any command that works in v1 works on v2 and v3. (also v2 and v3 scripts still use the extension `.ps1`). Can you please show a example that makes you think that Start-Job or Invoke-Command would not work, and maybe post a psudocode example of how you think it could work if you knew the right commands?

Comment: Anything that works in PS1 will work in v2 and v3. If you explain what you actually need to accomplish, someone may be able to suggest a solution that's more in keeping with PowerShell idioms.

Comment: While the accepted answer explains the syntax of `Start-Job`, it should be noted that `Start-Job` is _not_ equivalent to the Unix `nohup` utility, as the latter ensures that the process it launches stays alive even after the launching shell exits. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64708000/45375) to  a related question for how to achieve true `nohup`-like behavior on Windows (and on Unix).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
> Start-Job my.exe
```

Fails with this output:

```
Start-Job : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
At line:1 char:1
+ Start-Job my.exe
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Start-Job], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartJobCommand
```

Try this instead:

```
> Start-Job { & C:\Full\Path\To\my.exe }
```

It will work, and you will see output like this:

```
Id     Name            PSJobTypeName   State         HasMoreData     Location             Command
--     ----            -------------   -----         -----------     --------             -------
2      Job2            BackgroundJob   Running       True            localhost             & .\my.exe
```

I hope that is what you're looking for because your question is a bit vague.

Comment: The reason this works is that it creates a script block from which it executes your binary.  I'm hoping your question comes from the fact that Start-Job fails unexpectedly when you just hand it a binary you'd like it to run.

Comment: Eld, yes, that was exactly the problem I was encountering. You nailed it perfectly.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid script termination in case of console window closed?

Comment: You can run your command as a process instead using `Start-Process [my.exe] -WindowStyle hidden`. If you don't care about your program's I/O you can run it as-is, or you can specify files using the -redirect flags (see documentation).