# What is the equivalent of 'nohup' in linux PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-core, powershell-7.0

I very well know existence of [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19321903/what-is-the-equivalent-of-nohup-in-powershell). But that question is marked answered and I don't think it at all answers the original question.

The `$ nohup command` keeps executing command even if the parent process (shell) of nohup dies. More info here: [What's the difference between nohup and ampersand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15595374/whats-the-difference-between-nohup-and-ampersand).

In case of Win32 api, I see line [When the system is terminating a process, it does not terminate any child processes that the process has created. Terminating a process does not generate notifications for WH_CBT hook procedures.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/terminating-a-process). This is the desired behaviour I am asking about. This works with win32 powershell automatically. But with linux powershell's `Start-Job` it's merely background job in the powershell context in the sense that it gets killed when powershell gets killed.

Example:

```bsh
➜  ~ powershell-preview -c "Start-Job { /bin/sleep 1000 }"

Id     Name            PSJobTypeName   State         HasMoreData     Location             Command
--     ----            -------------   -----         -----------     --------             -------
1      Job1            BackgroundJob   Running       True            localhost             /bin/sleep 1000

➜  ~ ps ux  | grep sleep
mvaidya   166986  0.0  0.0   9032   664 pts/11   S+   18:59   0:00 grep --color=auto --exclude-dir=.bzr --exclude-dir=CVS --exclude-dir=.git --exclude-dir=.hg --exclude-dir=.svn --exclude-dir=.idea --exclude-dir=.tox sleep
```

Comment: As an  aside: even on Windows the child processes that run jobs created with `Start-Job` are killed when the launching shell exits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`Start-Job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/Start-Job) or PowerShell v6+'s [`&` background operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#background-operator-) isn't an option, because terminating the job will also terminate child processes launched from it, which jobs are - *both on Windows and on Unix-like platforms*.

However, you can achieve `nohup`-like behavior via the [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Start-Process) cmdlet:

---

**On *Unix*-like platforms**, you can combine `Start-Process` with `nohup`:
The following example launches a background PowerShell instance that stays alive even after you close the launching terminal; it emits a `.`  every second, and `nohup` collects both stdout and stderr output in file `nohup.out` in the current directory, appending to such a file if it already exists:

```
# Runs for 2 minutes and appends both stdout and stderr output to ./nohup.out
Start-Process nohup 'pwsh -nop -c "1..120 | % { write-host . -nonewline; sleep 1 }"'
```

**Caveat**: As of PowerShell 7.2, running this command via a **SSH** connection **only works if the connection was initiated *via `ssh`***, not via PowerShell's own SSH-based remoting cmdlets, such as [`Invoke-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command) and [`Enter-PSSession`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/enter-pssession)<sup>[1]</sup>.

For instance - **assuming that the user's default shell on the target computer is `pwsh`** (PowerShell), the following command could be used; note that **option `-t` is needed** in order to allocate a pseudo terminal (pty), so that `nohup` thinks its stdout is connected to a terminal and therefore sends its output to file `.\nohup.out`):

```
ssh -t <user>@<host> 'Start-Process nohup ''pwsh -nop -c \"1..120 | % { write-host . -nonewline; sleep 1 }\"'''
```

<sup>Note the surprising need for `\"` rather than just `"`, required to compensate for PowerShell's still-broken argument-passing to external programs as of PowerShell 7.1 - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59036879/45375).</sup>

By contrast, if the user's default shell on the target computer is a ***POSIX-compatible* shell** such as `bash`, use the following (run from PowerShell):

```
# IMPORTANT: If the target machine runs macOS rather than Linux, use the
#            `pwsh`'s *full path*, which is `/usr/local/bin/pwsh` by default.
ssh -t <user>@<host> 'nohup pwsh -nop -c ''1..120 | % { write-host . -nonewline; sleep 1 }'' & whoami >/dev/null'
```

<sup>Note the use of dummy command `whoami >/dev/null` after submitting the background job ( `&`), which is seemingly required to ensure that `nohup` gets enough time to actually launch its target command.</sup>

---

**On *Windows***, where `Start-Process` by default creates an independent process in a new console window, you can use `-WindowStyle Hidden` to launch that process in a hidden window that will remain alive independently of the launching shell.

```
# Runs for 2 minutes and appends success output to ./nohup.out
Start-Process -WindowStyle Hidden pwsh '-nop -c "1..120 | % { Add-Content -nonewline nohup.out -Value .; sleep 1 }"'
```

**Caveat**: This **does not work *as-is* work *remoting***:

- In a remoting sessio, `Start-Process` cannot launch the process in a separate (hidden) window this way, so **on exiting the remoting session the launched process is terminated as well**.
- However, you can **create a *disconnected* session** that remains alive on the target computer until it is explicitly deleted (or until the target computer reboots); alternatively, create a regular (connected) session explicitly and keep it as long as needed - though if the calling computer reboots before the task is completed, the task is again terminated (unless you explicitly disconnect the session first).

An example, using [`Invoke-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command)'s `-InDisconnectedSession` switch:

```
# Launch the command remotely, in a disconnected session, and
# return a session-information object:
$disconnSess = Invoke-Command -Computer <host> -InDisconnectedSession {
  Start-Process -WindowStyle Hidden pwsh '-nop -c "1..120 | % { Add-Content -nonewline nohup.out -Value .; sleep 1 }"'
}

# ... Let the command finish

# Remove the session again
Remove-PSSession $disconnSess
```

---

<sup>[1] These cmdlets do not allocate a pseudo terminal (pty), the absence of which causes `nohup` to print its output to stdout and stderr rather than to file `.\nohup.out`. Additionally, this unexpected, directly printed output can cause the remote PowerShell session to *crash*.</sup>

Comment: @ziyuang, when executed on the same machine, the process should live on. Via SSH, extra effort is needed, and it only works via `ssh` (not via PowerShell's remoting cmdlets) - please see my update.