# Run executable in powershell without waiting for return

Tags: powershell

This is really basic, but I can't find the answer.  The installer sets up my path so that I can just type the command:

ng serve

at the command prompt and the script runs.  I don't want to wait for this program to finish (it's a server, after all).  How do I launch the same script (it's a CMD script as far as I can tell) from Powershell without waiting for it to finish (and without having to find the source directory for the script)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**If it's acceptable to terminate the server when the PowerShell session exits**, use a **background job**:

In PowerShell (Core) 7+

```bash
ng server &
```

In Windows PowerShell, explicit use of [`Start-Job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/start-job) is required:

```bash
Start-Job { ng server }
```

Both commands return a job-information object, which you can either save in a variable (`$jb = ...`) or discard (`$null = ...`)

If the server process produces output you'd like to monitor, you can use the [`Receive-Job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/receive-job) cmdlet.

See the conceptual [about_Jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Jobs) topic for more information.

---

**If the server must continue to run even after the launching PowerShell session exits**, use the **[`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) cmdlet**, which on Windows launches an independent process in a *new console window* (by default); use the `-WindowStyle` parameter to control the visibility / state of that window:

```bash
Start-Process ng server # short for: Start-Process -FilePath ng -ArgumentList server
```

Note: On **Unix-like platforms**, where `Start-Process` doesn't support creating independent new terminal windows, you must **additionally use `nohup`** - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64708000/45375).

Comment: On Windows PowerShell 5.1, `Start-Process` with `-NoNewWindow` option create process (external GUI program) that will be terminated after PowerShell session exists. In order to run GUI program even after PowerShell session exists and without additional console window, `Start-Process -WindowStyle Hidden` worked. E.g. `Start-Process -WindowStyle Hidden winmergeu.exe  "/s /t text ""${file1}"" ""${file2}"""`

Comment: @aruku7230, `-NoNewWindow` has no effect on GUI-subystem  applications, and  the application always lives on after the launching PowerShell session exits.Similarly, the use of
`-WindowStyle` has no impact on the lifetime of the launched process (but `-WindowStyle Hidden` hides the process' window, both for console-subsystem and GUI subsystem applications).
.Only if the launched process is a console-subsystem application and you use `-NoNewWindow` does closing the calling window terminate the launched process too.