# Non-blocking Powershell script inside Power Automate flow

Tags: powershell, power-automate

I have a very simple Powershell script inside a Power Automate Desktop flow. The script starts a desktop application (just an *mstsc* command). So far so good. My problem is how to run the script as non-blocking, or maybe how to branch the flow and run another branch in parallel (if this is even possible), so I can continue running further steps of the flow, where I grab objects inside the open application window to execute certain tasks. My flow doesn't run beyond the Powershell script step because the application is still running so the flow stays running that step forever. As soon as I close the application window, the flow execution continues. Any ideas?

Comment: How do you run mstsc in your PS script? What if you use the 'start-process' cmdlet to run it? It shouldn't wait for the process to terminate and your flow should continue.

Comment: Oh thanks! Your answer made me go back to that alternative which I was considering after reading this <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64707869/what-is-the-equivalent-of-nohup-in-linux-powershell?noredirect=1&lq=1>. I had tried Start-Process, got a syntax error and left it, but now I corrected and it works. Feel free to write it as an answer to close it.

Comment: You're welcome, always glad to help. I will write an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some programs/commands will have to be terminated in order for a Powershell script to continue its execution.

By using the **Start-Process** cmdlet, you can have more control over this behavior and don't wait for a return code.
*(You can also run it as a job if launching it in a separate thread if required by using Start-Job, Invoke-Command, etc.)*

I will take cmd.exe as an example although there are other ways to deal with this one:

```
# This portion of code will wait for cmd.exe to be closed in order to continue
Write-Host "launching cmd.exe..."
cmd.exe
Write-Host "cmd.exe is closed, script will continue..."

# This portion of code will NOT wait for cmd.exe to be closed in order to continue
Write-Host "launching cmd.exe..."
Start-Process cmd.exe
Write-Host "cmd.exe is not closed but script continues..."
```